# console.log of backgroundColor shows "" instead of the color value

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an button element with id "btn". I want to console.log the background color property it shows blank instead. What is the problem? Thank you.

```js
let btnColor = document.getElementById("btn").style.backgroundColor;
console.log(btnColor)
```

```css
#btn{
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  background-color: #74992e;
}
```

```html
<button id="btn">Click on me</button>
```

Comment: You haven't defined `background-color` of the inline style of the button.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
let btnColor = window.getComputedStyle(document.getElementById(“btn”)).backgroundColor
console.log(btnColor)
```

it’s working fine for me

explain:
sometimes `window.getComputedStyle` will get the style object of an elem so that if you call `.backgroundColor` then it’s working fine

summary two functions :)

- window.getComputedStyle(element).backgroundColor
- element.style.backgroundColor